# Coefficient of Complex Fourier Series when f is odd

Tags: complex-numbers, fourier-series

What happens to coefficients of complex fourier series when the function $f$ is odd? We know $f(x)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_ne^{\frac{i\pi nx}{l}}$ and $c_n  =\frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^{l}f(x)e^{-\frac{i\pi nx}{l}}dx$.

I can rewrite $ e^{\frac{i\pi nx}{l}} $ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ and I assume $\cos$ terms would vanish but I am not sure if it helps. Can someone help on how to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your intuition is correct!

Notice that
$$\begin{split}c_n &=\frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^{l}f(x)e^{-\frac{2i\pi nx}{l}}dx\\
&=\frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^{l}f(-u)e^{\frac{2i\pi nu}{l}}du \text{ (change the variable $u=-x$)}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2l}\int_{-l}^{l}f(u)e^{\frac{2i\pi nu}{l}}du \text{ ($f$ is odd)}\\
&=-c_{-n}
\end{split}$$
This, in particular, implies that $c_0=0$. But also, the Fourier series of $f$ can be rewritten as
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} c_ne^{\frac{i\pi nx}{l}}=\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n\left(e^{\frac{2i\pi nt}{l}}-e^{-\frac{2i\pi nt}{l}}\right)=2i\sum_{n\geq 1}c_n\sin\left(\frac{2i\pi nt}{l}\right)$$

Comment: Doesn't $c_{0}$ vanish too since $f$ is odd?

Comment: Haha, good catch! fixed.

Comment: Also I just guess that $c_{n} = c_{-n}$ if $f$ is even because of symmetry. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. And you can apply the same reasoning to show that the $\sin$ functions all vanish in the Fourier series.